# apt-get - allow install of unconventional file

Tags: apt

I am looking to install .deb files that have been encrypted and then decrypted. During this process the names of the original files have been dropped and instead are a temporary gibberish value. I can install using 'dpkg -i' without issue but I was looking to use 'apt-get install' to avoid having to perform any cleanup for dependency issues. I did not see any options for apt-get to allow this type of functionality. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I.E - original package:  something-something-version-amd64.deb
      decrypted package: blahblah

```
  'dpkg -i blahblah' - success
  'apt-get install blahblah' - unrecognized file
```

Thanks!

Comment: `apt-get` only works with the Repositories.  It doesn't work with individual files and Debian packages directly as it in turn invokes `dpkg` installation commands behind the scenes.  (So no, `apt-get` can't do what you want it to do currently.)

Comment: apt-get does work with individual files. 'apt-get install ./<name_of_deb>' installs as expected

Comment: ^ muru - You did not understand the question

Comment: @asolak Use `dpkg` to install local .deb files and apt-get to install from the repositories is what you need to understand.

Comment: `apt-get` works only "offline" if `blahblah` ends with `.deb`

Comment: You want dependencies to be installed automatically, and you think apt-get is the way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things to consider:

(1) `dpkg` is designed to work with all packages.  `apt-get` is designed to work with repositories.

(2) `dpkg` is usually easier to work with for local packages.  There are exceptions, but `dpkg -i` can be used to install, then `apt-get install -f` can be used to get dependencies.

---

The above aside, you *can* technically install packages by doing `sudo apt-get install ./PACKAGE.deb`, however I've had mixed results with this.  It's better to use `dpkg` to install those packages, and let `apt-get install -f` handle the dependencies afterwards, in my opinion.

Comment: I appreciate the real-world feedback. If you could provide details regarding your mixed results that would be great to review.